# How do I use .net standard with .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I dont think my question itself was very descriptive of my issue, so I will describe what I am doing and how I am trying to do it.

We have an old project that utilizes MEFS for various plugins. We are trying to convert it to a dotnet core application so that we can deploy it to different operating systems. From what I have read, .net core only partially support MEFS. Microsoft.Composition provides some basic support for plugins, but there is no Microsoft.Componentmodel.Composition, so you cant load plugins from a directory (which is what I need to do).

After reading about .net Standard, I am under the impression that it provides a set of APIs that bridge the gap between .net core and the .net framework. As a demo, I have created a solution with 3 projects. A .net core project, .net standard project, and a .net framework project. The Core project references the Standard project, and the Standard project calls some code in the Framework project. I am basing this model on [Announcing .NET Core 2.0 Preview 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/28/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-2/)  (scroll down to "Reference .NET Framework libraries from .NET Standard").

The problem I find is that my Framework code always throws a TypeInitializationException. I believe that when the code is compiled, it recognizes a library from the .net Standard framework, but at runtime it is actually using the same library in the .net Core framework (which is lighter and misses some things).

The class I am referencing is **System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateCatalog**

Is there a way to specify that I want to load an assembly from the .net Standard SDK rather than the .net Core SDK? It seems like there is no benefit in using them in tandem if the Standard dlls will be ignored. Here is a screenshot of my setup and the exception I am getting.

[image: My exception]

Do I just have a misunderstanding of the fundamentals here?

Thanks

Comment: Read about .NET-Standard here https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/library - In short it is just an abstract definition

Comment: @SirRufo I watched the introduction to .net core 2.0 and they made it sound like standard would unify core and framework, at least to a degree, so that you can deploy to various operating systems. I guess I misunderstood? Does that mean there is no way to utilize the Framework version of System.ComponentModel.Composition?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is .Net standard is the common API referenced by all the frameworks, in your question you implied that your standard project is calling code in your framework project, I believe this maybe why the project is throwing an exception.

Where your projects reference assemblies you should be seeing warnings that indicate that this is the case (little yellow triangle)

I found this article useful
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt842506.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396